# CasperJS errors - where are they?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs, error-reporting

Why CasperJS does not show JS errors? I have a code:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.start('http://casperjs.org/');
casper.then(function() {
    this.echo('First Page: ' + this.getTitle());
});
var a=null;
console.log(a.b.c);
casper.run();
```

I run it with `casperjs sample.js`, but see no warning about `a.b.c`, it just stops execution and that's it. Is it possible to see errors my script produces anywhere?

Comment: `var a = null` doesn't make any sense maybe `var a = { b: 9 }` or something similar

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS 2.x has introduced a bug which prevents the printing of *some* errors. Here are some the related GitHub issues: [#12973](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12973), [#13741](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/13741), [#14399](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/14399). The bug still persists in the currently available version 2.1.1, but there is a patch available (see [commit](https://github.com/Vitallium/qtwebkit/commit/e09b87bfe2b3ad6004d31894ee58bd611c8e3e39) at the end of the first issue I linked to).

Since CasperJS is built on top of PhantomJS, it has the same limitation.

---

PhantomJS and CasperJS don't show many errors by default, so you have to register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-2_caspererrors-js)) to see more.

Comment: No, it did not work for me. It throws errors if I have them inside functions, but not outside, like in my example.

Comment: As I said. It's a PhantomJS bug. There is nothing you can do except built your own patched version of PhantomJS with that patch that I linked to. Or you could downgrade to PhantomJS 1.x.